# Migrating website from php 5.2 to php 5.6, encountering memcache errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

EDIT:
perhaps I could make this simpler: when my website is running on php-5.2, everything works. When i try to run it on php-5.6 I get this error:
[image: ```sh]

The installed libraries are all the same:

```
RUN \
  apt-get install -y \
    php5-memcache \
    memcached \
    libapache2-mod-php5
```

any ideas?

---

Note* I have tried installing php5-memcached, and this is what happens next.

---

After installing php5-memcache,

I get this warning message:

```html
Message: Memcached::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Then the page break with a Fatal Error:

```html
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in  auth_model.php on line 800 E_ERROR Error in file  auth_model.php
```

This may be the breaking code ( auth_model.php on line 800):

```php
    $memcached_profile=$this->memcached->get($memcached_key);
```

But it seems more like its memcache that's not working

These are the versions:
Current PHP version: 5.6.40-0+deb8u4
Current CodeIgniter version: 2.0.2
Memcache version: 1.4.21

```sh
>php -i | grep memcache  
libmemcached version => 1.0.18
```

by the way, it makes no difference whether the memcached service is started or not!

Comment: What version of memcache are you using? have you update your memcache package to latest?

Comment: using memcache Version  3.0.8   and    using memcached Version  2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

MemCached constructor optional parameter must be a string, and not an array

```php
/* For Creating a persistent instance */
$m2 = new Memcached('story_pool');
```

You should find out where your memcache persistent id is defined

Comment: any quick way to find out?

Comment: Look in `application/config`
to see if there is not a `memcached.php` file

or you can try to search for a text starting with `$this->load->driver('cache'...` in your project

Comment: found this:                         $this->m = new Memcache();

Comment: Is it in the `Memcached_library` file?

Comment: i have the memcached.php file, but it doesn't have that line of code in it. it points to localhost

Comment: this line doesn't exist with the word 'cache' in it: $this->load->driver('cache'..

Comment: `memcached.php` is the configuration file, you should have a codeigniter `memcached_library` that use it.

Where was the line `$this->m = new Memcache();`?

Comment: that is the only file that contains the string "memcached_library": it says at the end of the file: "/* End of file memcached_library.php"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196228/discussion-between-jchache-and-octavian).

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the [memcache](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) extension, but your application is attempting to use the `Memcached` class, which is defined by the [memcache**d**](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) extension.

The memcache and memcached extensions are similar, but not identical, and not interchangeable. Of the two, memcache (the one you have installed) is unmaintained and incompatible with current versions of PHP, so you should install the memcached extension (which your application expects to have available).

Comment: I hear what you're saying, however, the package installation was the same on 5.2 as on 5.6. I didn't have memcached on 5.2, and it worked fine. The code has only had a very small change to adjust to 5.6, and by that I mean only a single line of code, and that was to do with preg_replace. So all else is the same, yet now I get  a memcached error, and installing memcached doesn't help, it merely leads to the question that makes up the second half of the post.